# How to LEFT JOIN two external JSON url

Tags: javascript, json, alasql

I'm trying to accomplish below result using external JSON. I searched on google and stackverflow and i couldn't find any answer. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you in advance.

```
people = 
[{id: 1, name: "Tom", carid: 1},
{id: 2, name: "Bob", carid: 1},
{id: 3, name: "Sir Benjamin Rogan-Josh IV", carid: 2}];

cars=
[{id: 1, name: "Ford Fiesta", color: "blue"},
{id: 2, name: "Ferrari", color: "red"},
{id: 3, name: "Rover 25", color: "Sunset Melting Yellow with hints of yellow"}];

var res = alasql('SELECT people.name AS person_name, cars.name, cars.color \
    FROM ? people LEFT JOIN ? cars ON people.carid = cars.id',[people, cars]);
```

Result:

```
[{"person_name":"Tom","name":"Ford Fiesta","color":"blue"},{"person_name":"Bob","name":"Ford Fiesta","color":"blue"},{"person_name":"Sir Benjamin Rogan-Josh IV","name":"Ferrari","color":"red"}]
```

---

**This is my code to access external JSON:**

people.json

```
[{id: 1, name: "Tom", carid: 1},{id: 2, name: "Bob", carid: 1}, {id: 3, name: "Sir Benjamin Rogan-Josh IV", carid: 2}]
```

cars.json

```
[{id: 1, name: "Ford Fiesta", color: "blue"},{id: 2, name: "Ferrari", color: "red"},{id: 3, name: "Rover 25", color: "Sunset Melting Yellow with hints of yellow"}]
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
         $.getJSON('http://example.com/people.json', function(data) { 
                    people = JSON.parse(data);
                }); 

         $.getJSON('http://example.com/cars.json', function(data) { 
                    cars = JSON.parse(data);
                }); 


        var res = alasql('SELECT people.name AS person_name, cars.name, cars.color \
        FROM ? people LEFT JOIN ? cars ON people.carid = cars.id',[people, cars]);

        document.getElementById('id01').textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
}):
```

This is the error I'm getting in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (list.html:26)
at c (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at l (jquery.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: What exactly does not work in the code you posted? Does `alasql` throw an error?

Comment: The code is working fine but I don't know how to access the JSON using API url.

Comment: What do you mean by "using API url"? You already have two literals in your code.

Comment: I've edited my question for better understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ah, with that code snippet now the question makes sense. The problem is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over each person and find the corresponding car details, In this way you can accomplish your task.

Please find below working code with simple `for of`. You can also use `map` operator as well

```js
people = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Tom",
    carid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bob",
    carid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Sir Benjamin Rogan-Josh IV",
    carid: 2
  }
];

cars = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Ford Fiesta",
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ferrari",
    color: "red"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Rover 25",
    color: "Sunset Melting Yellow with hints of yellow"
  }
];

const result = [];
for (const peop of people) {
  const car = cars.filter(d => d.id === peop.carid)[0];
  result.push({
    person_name: peop.name,
    name: car.name,
    color: car.color
  });
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: My trouble is how do I access external JSON objects in this solution.

First JSON Url: https://externaldomain.com/json/people.json

Second JSON Url: https://externaldomain.com/json/cars.json

Comment: what do you mean by extenal JSON object here ? Isn't the output of my solution is required output ?

Comment: I am not able to open the URL's shared by you

Comment: That is example url but the real url will have the same JSON object in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
 var requestpeop = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestpeop.open('GET', 'people.json', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
    requestpeop.send(null);

    if (requestpeop.status === 200) {// That's HTTP for 'ok'
      var people =  JSON.parse(requestpeop.responseText);
    }

    var requestcar = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestcar.open('GET', 'car.json', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
    requestcar.send(null);

    if (requestcar.status === 200) {// That's HTTP for 'ok'
      var cars = JSON.parse(requestcar.responseText);
    }
```